# Is there a good way to handle multiple arrays from an asm.js module?

Tags: javascript, asm.js

In particular, I'm trying to implement a vector math module to handle vectors and matrices.

My initial plan was the following: use a big heap for all objects of the same kind (say, 4x4 matrices), reserve some space for inter-calculations, and access the rest of the matrices by offset. Here's an example of my code:

```
'use strict';

function Mat4(stdlib, foreign, heap) {
    'use asm';

    var H = new stdlib.Float32Array(heap);

    function identity(n) {
        n = n|0;

        var offset = 0;
        offset = ((n|0) << 6)|0;

        H[((offset|0)) >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 4) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 8) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 12) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 16) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 20) >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 24) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 28) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 32) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 36) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 40) >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 44) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 48) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 52) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 56) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[((offset|0) + 60) >> 2] = 1.0;

        return ((offset|0) >> 2)|0;
    }

    return {
        identity: identity
    };
};

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4096);
var fArray = new Float32Array(buffer);
var mod = Mat4(window, {}, buffer);

var dmat4 = {
    counter: 0
};

dmat4.identity = function() {
    var offset = mod.identity(dmat4.counter++);
    return fArray.subarray(offset, offset + 16);
};
```

This seems to be working, but appears to be much slower than just creating a Float32Array in place and filling it with values. My guess is that all the offset math takes most of the time, and it's not being optimized on compiling this asm.js code.

But maybe I'm missing something, and this code can be improved?

Comment: What exactly did you time? Do you have a jsperf link for this? The compilation of asm.js code ahead of time will take time, so make sure your timed calls only include the identity invocation, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Reworked the code in the following way:

```
'use strict';

function Mat4(stdlib, foreign, heap) {
    'use asm';

    var H = new stdlib.Float32Array(heap);
    var I = new stdlib.Uint8Array(heap);

    function identity() {
        var offset = 0;
        offset = ((I[0]|0 + 16) << 6)|0;
        I[0] = I[0]|0 + 1;

        H[offset >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[(offset + 4) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 8) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 12) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 16) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 20) >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[(offset + 24) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 28) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 32) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 36) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 40) >> 2] = 1.0;
        H[(offset + 44) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 48) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 52) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 56) >> 2] = 0.0;
        H[(offset + 60) >> 2] = 1.0;

        return (offset >> 2)|0;
    }

    return {
        identity: identity
    };
};

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(65536);
var array = new Float32Array(buffer);
var mod = Mat4(window, {}, buffer);

var dmat4 = {};

dmat4.identity = function() {
    var offset = mod.identity();
    return array.subarray(offset, offset + 16);
};

dmat4.create = dmat4.identity;

dmat4.identity();
```

Now works only 2 times slower than glMarix approach (this is expected, I guess);

Comment: Now, another funny thing. If I comment out "use asm";, it starts working almost as fast as glMatrix in NightlyFF. And it's already slightly faster than glMatrix in Chrome.